# Get the dropdown part of jQuery autocomplete combobox

Tags: jquery-ui, combobox, jquery-autocomplete

I would like to get the html element corresponding to the auto-complete list i.e. dropdown part that opens as I type into the input element of jQuery combobox. How would I get this dropdown element using jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about jQueryUI autocomplete, you can access the `menu`'s element using:

```
$('autocomplete_selector').data("autocomplete").menu.element;
```

So in the context of the `open` event, you could do something like this:

```
$("input").autocomplete({
    open: function (event, ui) {
        // menu is a jQuery object.
        var menu = $(this).data("autocomplete").menu.element;
    }
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/PvgGw/

---

For the combobox widget you'll need to jump through a few more hoops, since the `input` is dynamically generated:

```
$("combobox_selector")
    .data("combobox")
    .wrapper
    .find("input")
    .data("autocomplete")
    .menu
    .element;
```

Comment: Would this work for jQuery combobox having id ='abc': $('#abc').('.ui-auto-complete) ?

Comment: What do you mean by "jQuery combobox"?

Comment: @Andrews - the autocomplete combobox available in jQuery-ui, as at this link: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#option-source

Comment: @Andrews - I tried your approach but it doesn't work: $("#combobox123").data("autocomplete").menu.element is always  null. But, if I try $("#combobox123").next(".ui-autocomplete") then I get a non-null object. So there may be something incorrect about your expression.

Comment: That's because your selector is selecting a `select` element and not the `input` that the autocomplete plugin is attached to underneath. Please see my update.

Comment: I am still having problems with your approach. I need to determine if the dropdown portion has focus, and when I use your selector with .is(":focus"), it always return a false.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? The autocomplete widget has its own `focus` event that might come in handy. Does checking the visibility of the menu help at all?

Comment: I am doing something  if the autocomplete dropdown is not opened i.e. collapsed. May be something other than focus would help, like if its visible or open. Thanks